# Non-metrics give "pathological" solutions: what does this mean?

Tags: terminology, distance-functions, metric, measure-theory

In [this](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf) set of slides on DTW, slide 25 says that we generally prefer metrics over measures because,

> "Non-Metrics can sometimes give pathological solutions when clustering or classifying data etc."

What does this actually mean? What is a "pathological" solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pathological solution is one whose stability is so poor that any answer provided by that solution is unreliable. For example, the mean value of a finite number of outcomes of a Cauchy distributed random variable can always be calculated. However, any such answer is pathological in the sense  that if  more values of the random variable are collected the mean is increasingly unbounded both  above and below.

Comment: Although it's difficult to say exactly what the author of the slides means by "pathological," this answer is not relevant to the question of "measures" *vs* "metrics" in a DTW setting and in fact may be misleading.

Comment: @Whuber What? The applicable sentence is "Non-Metrics can sometimes give pathological solutions when clustering or classifying data etc." on pp. 25  and 26." The  frequency of the example Cauchy  distribution RV mean pathology can be reduced by trimming, e.g., 1% trimming would reduce the pathological instability to some extent and higher trimming, e.g., 20%, would be better. The question here is what does a *pathological solution* mean, and I have answered that question; it means *wrong*. The question pertains to *meaning* of words , i.e.,  terminology, and is context independent.

Comment: Carl, the word "pathological" has a special meaning in mathematical circles.  That meaning is not "wrong," but closer to "unusual" or "something we would like to be able to rule out" or "unexpected" or "not fitting in with the nice theories we would like to develop."

Comment: @whuber Since we are splitting hairs from [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pathos): *The Greek word pathos means "suffering," "experience," or "emotion."...Though "pathology" is not literally "the study of suffering," it is "the study of diseases."* If you will the mathematical meaning of *pathological* is borrowed from medicine, "sick answers" would be the analogy.

Comment: @whuber Since we are discussing this *ad nauseam*, what is your opinion of *pathological* as a synonym of *not robust*?

Comment: I have never seen any statistical literature that uses those terms synonymously.   Quoting non-statistical sources like Webster's is of little use here.

Comment: @whuber To claim that the etymology of a word does not contribute to its connotation goes too far for my tastes. In point of fact, the etymology and meaning are frequently closely aligned by transference. To make a claim that transference of meaning is inapplicable would require more evidence than the obverse, and as yet I am skeptical as to the lack of same in this case. It may be that my perceptions more follow a Gestalt law of grouping than yours, but that would not, by itself, invalidate my opinion. Perhaps if you specify how you see the word usage being unique for math that would help.

Comment: @whuber I hate to say this, but, as someone who studied pathology to the level of eligibility for specialist medical certification in that field, when I say that the analogy between the medical and mathematical usage of the word "pathological" appears to be fairly exact, one should really expect to have to work at convincing me otherwise.